# SQL Replication 'The process could not connect to Subscriber'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication, database-replication

I have three servers, all Windows 2008 + SQL Server 2008 R2:

- Server 'A'
- Server 'B'
- Server 'Z'

A and B are publishers, Z is a subscriber to both A and B. The subscriptions are configured in 'Push' mode (i.e. From Distributor to Subscriber).

Replication from A to Z works perfectly.

Replication from B to Z fails with the message *'The process could not connect to Subscriber 'ServerZ''*. This message displays in the sync status on the Distributor (Server B).

The connection is being run with SQL Logins, and I've checked all the passwords many times - and I can connect through SQL Management Studio without any issues - but when the same credentials are put into Replication, it fails...

Why? And how do I stop it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar issue.  I've also seen it before and somehow solved it but can't find any notes I may have made at the time.  Very annoying.  Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: My problem at least was that there were 2 versions of MS SQL installed, on the 64 bit version.  The configuration wasn't correct in the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out in the end the issue was to do with the Port numbers replication was attempting to connect on (which were non-standard).

It seems the order which you specify the ports in the SQL network configuration dictates which one it will use if one is not specified in the connection attempt.

Comment: which port it was using ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are also using Sql Server Aliases to connect to the remote SQL servers, this trick will work for you.

I created SQL Server Alias under Native Client Configuration (32 bit) and my SQL Studio was enabling me to connect to the remote server.

I just created the same alias under Native Client Configuration (without 32 bit) option and it simply worked.